# How to add words in openears dictionary and it's language model and .gram file

Tags: iphone, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, openears

I am using open ears sdk for speech recognition and synthesis in iphone programming but it's dictionary and .gram file and it's language model file contain only 8 standard words and I need more words in my app. if I m adding new words in it's .gram and .language model and .dic file, my app is crashing.

Please suggest me how to add new words in openears  because I need to add 20 words in these files.

Answer (score 3):

OpenEars developer here. Please use the quickstart tutorial, it only takes a few minutes and shows you how to use OpenEars' LanguageModelGenerator class, which will answer your question and give you a copy/paste-able code snippet: http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial If you have follow-up questions, the OpenEars forums are a good place to ask them: http://www.politepix.com/forums/openears

Comment: Thank u sir but in that I didn't find solution of my problem and I have spent lot's of time on that

Comment: http://www.politepix.com/2012/11/02/openears-tips-1-create-a-language-model-before-runtime-from-a-text-file/

Comment: I have got solution by above link thank u for giving me your precious time.

Comment: I'm glad my blog post helped, but it isn't the answer to the question you are asking above, which is just about using the default functionality of LanguageModelGenerator and is covered in the docs and tutorial. Using the explanation in the blog post to generate a custom language model is much more effort than is necessary. If it works for you that's great, but later readers of this question should really just spend 10 minutes on the tutorial since the single method call needed for creating custom language models is covered there.

Comment: @Halle  how to use if i want the speak language in Chinese.